# Repeat a question using a "While or Do While Loop"

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I want to prompt the user for a number. If the number is less than 10, I want to prompt the user to choose another number.

```
let question = Number(prompt("Please pick a number"));
console.log(question);
```

I started my code like the image above, this console logs the response as a number and not a string.

When I format the (while, or do while loop) I get problems and my console log starts running infinitely.

[image]

After researching this, there are two things that I don't understand,

1. Why is it running infinitely?
2. Secondly, I don't know how to get the prompt to repeat itself.

Thank you

I tried research W3, and other sites but couldn't find an example that included a prompt.

Comment: Please copy/paste all code in to the question - images of code are not helpful as we can't edit them

Comment: You need to ask for another number **in the loop.** Unless you do that, the number doesn't change, and thus the condition also won't.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
let question = "Pick a number ";
let answer =Number(prompt(question));
while (answer < 10){
answer = Number(prompt(question));
}
```

Here I am storing the input value from the prompt to the variable named answer

while-loop will keep calling the prompt until the value of the answer is greater than or equal to 10
Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

## First of all thanks for responding, and here I think I can answer.

```
let question = Number(prompt("Please pick a number"));
 while (question < 10){
  question = Number(prompt("Please pick a number"))
 }
```

1. I made a variable equal to a number value for my string
   "Please pick a number."
2. In the while loop, it is self explanatory, the part that was confusing me earlier was not knowing what to write within the curly brackets. When I wrote question by itself, the computer froze.
3. Then after asking my teacher, she said to add another prompt.
4. So we added question = Number(prompt("Please pick a number")).
5. This repeated the loop and asked the same string while converting it to a number which allowed it to be checked again to see if the value is less than 10.

Thank you for helping me with my question.